Network Manager requires a bunch of manual configuration to connect to WPA Enterprise wifi networks. Why?
Connecting to WPA enterprise networks on Windows is straightforward:

Select the network
Enter your username and password
Confirm that, yes, the network is expected to be available at this location

...and you're good to go.
Network Manager, on the other hand, requires a ton of manual configuration steps whose defaults often don't work, at least on Ubuntu flavors. It doesn't even default to using the system CA certificates and forces you to select one.
Eduroam is a good example - it's so complex that Eduroam has to provide an app to connect to the network on new devices. Why is this the case? Is Windows just trying a bunch of things until they work, or is it privvy to some additional autoconfiguration protocol that Linux doesn't/can't use?

Because nobody has implemented the "works in most cases" user-friendly windows frontend. Like with every other software, be it microsoft word, Google Chrome or GNU bash, someon did or did not implement something some way or another. This is your chance to go in and fix that for the user interface that you care about (e.g. Gnome).

I don't have good authoritative sources (someone chime in if they do) as my experience is mostly with the Linux side, but I think it's that most of the options in NetworkManager/WPA Supplicant simply aren't available in Windows without outside software. If Windows supported EAP-TTLS or all the various inner EAP protocols then their settings would probably be just as complex.
That would limit it to mostly PEAP with MSCHAPv2, or PEAP with a weird inner TLS with management-tool-distributed client cert.  That's combined with a default behavior of trust-on-first-use for the CA cert (the part where you confirm that you expect the network to be here).
NetworkManager can't architecturally support trust-on-first-use (it has no certificate store, and it's dependent on outside WPA software which doesn't provide intermediate files from the middle of the authentication process to approve or disapprove), but the rest could easily be done through a client with an easy mode.  Something like a future version of PlasmaNM's tray applet could just take the user name and password and prompt for a CA cert and assume it was PEAP-MSCHAPv2.

AFAIK, wpa_supplicant does provide an interface for implementing trust-on-first-use, and NM does already have the concept of storing certs associated with a connection profile. (iwd of course insists on being completely isolated.) The largest WPA-Enterprise network (eduroam) could be configured without it, using public CA verification.

@grawity I've been developing an application back by NM.  It does not store files.  It only reads files you happen to have stored from the FS.  I also have doubts about the security of using the global cert chain to validate a wi-fi network because it's not like you're validating a website's claim to their dns.
From the supplicant config file comments: "If ca_cert and ca_path are not included, server certificate will not be verified. This is insecure and a trusted CA certificate should always be configured when using EAP-TLS/TTLS/PEAP." I can't find TOFU for supplicant in searches.

Modern wpa_supplicant has domain_suffix_match= which if specified makes it work exactly like you're validating a website's claim to their DNS; e.g. current Android versions require specifying it when "Use system CAs" is specified; it could generally be pre-filled from the @realm part of the identity whenever it has one.

I think only eduroam works that way, and is part of why eduroam is that complex.  For everyone else it's just a file for a local private CA.
